# Following C code why it is correct to use graph->array[i].head and graph->array[i]->head gives error?

Tags: c, graph

I know that `.` is used when there is a direct access to a variable in the structure and `->` is used when you are accessing a variable of a structure through a pointer to that structure. Also `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`

Here we are accessing the pointer variable `head` of structure `AdjList` through a pointer stored in `graph->array[i]` but still using `.` for access.

`graph->array[i].head = *((*graph).array+i).head`

`graph->array[i]->head = (* *((*graph).array+i)).head`

```
// A structure to represent an adjacency list node 
struct AdjListNode 
{ 
    int dest; 
    struct AdjListNode* next; 
}; 
  
// A structure to represent an adjacency list 
struct AdjList 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode *head;  
}; 
  
// A structure to represent a graph. A graph  
struct Graph 
{ 
    int V; 
    struct AdjList* array; 
}; 

// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices 
struct Graph* createGraph(int V) 
{ 
    struct Graph* graph =  
        (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph)); 
    graph->V = V; 
  
    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of  
    // array will be V 
    graph->array =  
      (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList)); 
  
    // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by  
    // making head as NULL 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i) 
        graph->array[i].head = NULL; 
  
    return graph; 
}
```

But when we do tree traversal we do `root->left->left = (*(*root).left).left`  then it works fine.

If anyone can help me understand this with memory diagram that would be a great help, I made this memory diagram for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: `head` is an `struct AdjListNode*` so `head[i]` is a `struct AdjListNode`

Comment: yes, I know that. I have doubt on the syntax to access `head`, why `graph->array[i]->head` gives error ?

Comment: Because [] dereferences the pointer?

Comment: When you have an array why is it `array[1].x` and not `array[1]->x`? Same thing

Comment: Off-Topic: The size of an object is measured in bytes, this part "Size of array will be V " is missleading, i would use the word length. Why do you use a `int` for the array length and not `size_t`?

Comment: Do you understand that the `[]`-operator works on pointers and not arrays? A array variable decays to a pointer when you access an element (or when you do anything else, expect cases like the `sizeof` operator) and therefor `[]` works on array variables as well. `int *p=malloc(sizeof *p); p[0]=2;` is exactly the same as `int *p=malloc(sizeof *p); *p=2;`

Comment: @user253751 yes i know how array and pointer works, I have doubt on structure member access, why `.` used instead of `->`  which gives error?

Comment: Because the array elements consist of structs, not of pointers to structs. If it isn't a pointer, don't use `->`.